# Node is not defined (not even node -v) Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Hi according to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196257/node-is-not-defined) I can't even get the version of nodejs on windows8, what's going on?

Weird things is that on cmd it works but not the provided node cli?

[image]

Comment: Try instead entering [`process.version`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a Node terminal...which means it's expecting JavaScript code. Try `node -v` from `cmd`.

```
node -v
```

is not valid JavaScript, so you're getting an error.

Comment: Well then there's no issue ;) Node is running fine.